# Error - 'rows' is not a member of 'string' unsure as to why?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a check box in a grid view to set a 1 or 0 (true / false) and I am getting an error with the code behind

rows is not a member of string

this link here:

```
 Dim ID As String = [ID].Rows(dgRow.DataItemIndex).Cells(0).Text
```

I am not sure why, I am a complete newbie to this thing, please go easy, here is my code behind.

```
Public Sub checkbox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)       'Handles checkbox.CheckedChanged
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BusinessSignUpsConnectionString").ConnectionString


    Dim box As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim tblcell As TableCell = CType(box.Parent, TableCell)
    Dim dgRow As GridViewRow = CType(tblcell.Parent, GridViewRow)

    Dim ID As String = [ID].Rows(dgRow.DataItemIndex).Cells(0).Text


    Dim insertSQL As String

    If box.Checked = True Then
        insertSQL = "UPDATE BusinessSignups "
        insertSQL &= "SET contacted=1 "
        insertSQL &= "WHERE [ID]= @ID "
    Else
        insertSQL = "UPDATE BusinessSignups "
        insertSQL &= "SET contacted=0 "
        insertSQL &= "WHERE [ID]= @ID "
    End If

    Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(insertSQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacted", contacted)
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch Err As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error", 65584, "Insertion Error")
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: What is [ID] and where is it defined?

Comment: you define `ID` as a string then you try to get a row from it `[ID].Rows` (strings dont have rows). I think you need the gridview control name in place of `[ID]`

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is named `ID` then you can't use the same name for a variable, it will shadow the variable from the class scope inside the method. Use a different name for the variable:

```
Dim identity As String = [ID].Rows(dgRow.DataItemIndex).Cells(0).Text
```

Getting past that error, the next is that you are setting the wrong parameter with a variable that doesn't exist. You want to use the name `"@ID"` with the variable from above:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", identity)
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, but that still results in the same error - changed both as suggested. The above code that I got was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927272/vb-net-make-gridview-checkbox-field-update-boolean-field-in-database
this is why I used @contacted as the value...

Comment: @user2034164: Then `ID` is not a grid view but a string, wherever you have declared it. What's the name of your grid view?